# using preg_replace to add backslash before single quote

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to add a backslash before single quotes using preg_replace() php function ?

Answer (score 4):

In case you are not trying to escape Database input:

```
$string = str_replace("'", "\\'", $string);
```

In case you are:

Please consider using the appropriate escaping function. (E.g. mysql_real_escape_string) or just use prepared statements.

Comment: +1 for "Please consider using the appropriate escaping functions".

Comment: Just a note to the future visitors: use mysqli_real_escape_string() for mySQL and pg_real_escape_string() for postgreSQL on PHP>5.5--(mysql_real_escape_string() is deprecated) or alternatively use addslashes() if you cant find a DBMS specific function.

Answer (score 0):

just use the function **str_replace** to replace every instance of ' to \'

Comment: it is good to show an illustration of how to use the function like in above answer. Another solution is to replace a single quote with two single quotes-a native approach in SQL. By the way, I didn't downvote your answer.